# Merge Excel rows based on single field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a list of people that attended several webinar sessions - the Excel Sheet has a separate row for each session individually, but that is the only field that varies.
[image: Data Sample]

I am trying to combine the data in Excel so that I have  | Bob | Smith | bob@1.com | Main Street | 1,2,4

I have tried pivot tables etc, and I can get the data to the point where it shows
[image: Picot Table Result]

But I cannot figure out how to combine the last column...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2010+, I suggest using Power Query.

- `Data --> Get & Transform --> From Table/Range`
- Select all the columns except `Session`
- Group By:

  - New Column Name: Grouped
  - Operation: All Rows

[image]

- Add Custom Column

  - New Column Name: `Session`
  - Formula:  `=Table.Column([Grouped],"Session")`

[image]

- Select the double arrow at the top of the sessions column and

  - Extract values
  - Separator --> Comma
- Delete the extraneous Table column
- Save and load.

Generated **M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Session", Int64.Type}, {"First Name", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, {"Email", type text}, {"Address", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Address"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Session=nullable number, First Name=nullable text, Last Name=nullable text, Email=nullable text, Address=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Session", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Session")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Session", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Voila:

[image]

Comment: You are seriously awesome. Exactly what I was looking for - would have never figured it out - thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the Pivot table you already have:
[image]

You can remove Session and add this formula instead in the second row:

```
= Textjoin(", ", TRUE , IF([Email column in original table] = C2, [Session column in original table],""))
```

And then hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter